# Is there any way to specify your own vocabulary while using `com.google.schemaorg` java library?

Tags: java, schema.org, json-ld

I am creating a microservice that returns search results as json-LD while largely following schema.org semantics. However, in the search results I am also including some fields that are not defined on schemadotorg.

For such scenarios I am creating my **own json-LD objects** in the results that my service is returning. As far as creating an object that is only using schema.org semantics is concerned the following dependency is doing its job quite well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mautini</groupId>
    <artifactId>schemaorg-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But the problem occurs when I want have my own json-Ld object, in that case I am trying to add my own context to the object and have not been able to do it. Specially while the search result that I am trying to return is a merger of both schema.org and my custom vocabulary. I am trying to return something like the following Json-ld:

```
[
 {
    "@context": "http://www.myowncontext.com",
    "@type": "Event",
    "mycustomProperty": {
      "value": "My custom value",
      "vocabulary": "http://www.myowncontext.com/mycustomProperty"
    },
    "displayTemplate": "GRID_EVENT"
  },
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Event",
    "location": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "Denver",
        "addressRegion": "CO",
        "postalCode": "80209",
        "streetAddress": "7 S. Broadway"
      },
      "name": "The Hi-Dive"
    },
    "name": "Typhoon with Radiation City",
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "price": "13.00",
      "priceCurrency": "USD",
      "url": "http://www.ticketfly.com/purchase/309433"
    },
    "startDate": "2013-09-14T21:30"
  }
]
```

Is there any way to create an object with my own context using the library that I am using? Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: assuming that there is a vocabulary specification at `myowncontext.com`, the structure is valid and is visible on JSON-LD Playground and Structured Data Linter. However, what is the purpose of defining `@Event` in `myowncontext.com` since that `@Type` is defined in schema.org? I can understand your desire to create a new `@Type` but not a duplicate `@Type`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, reason for having a duplicate type is that there are some fields in my event that does not exist in the schema.org event.

Comment: Have you solved this? If not, what happens if you change your context to: `{ "@context": ["http://schema.org/", {"@vocab": "http://www.myowncontext.com/"} }`? Instead of trying to redefine the entire type, just extend it with your custom property.